# Can I rename the View Report button in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2012

I was wondering if it is possible to rename the button **View Report** in SSRS or even add some command buttons with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. That button can't be edited.

Up until SSRS 2016, the amount of customization possible in SSRS outside of the report canvas was close to zero. With 2016, there have been some improvements, but I believe that button is still not customizable.